# Ember.js find() does not work with parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, find, ember-data

I'm trying a simple post retrieval app with ember. Everything works fine as long as i'm not passing arguments to the find() function:

This works great:

```
return this.store.find('post')
```

But not these:

```
return this.store.find('post', { title: 'title1' })

return this.store.find('post', {})
```

The server returns exactly the same JSON regardless of the parameters, but Ember doesn't seem to process it when there's arguments. The store stays empty.

Here's the complete code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('myPosts');
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'api/v1/'
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    title : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    body : DS.attr( 'string' )
});

App.MyPostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function() {
        return this.store.find('post', { title: 'title1' })
    },

    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});
```

In all cases I never get any error, the queries are processed just fine and I've checked in chrome DevTools that the JSON returned by the server is the same.

Here's the JSON returned.

```
{"post": [{"body": "a body", "title": "title1"}]}
```

The handelbars template is simply:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="myPosts">
    <div class = "postsWrapper">
        {{#each}}
            <div>{{this}}</div>
            <div>title: {{title}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</script>
```

Here's the output i get with this.store.find('post', { title: 'title1' }):

```
<App.Post:ember382:null>
title:
```

Here's the one with i get with no parameters:

```
<App.Post:ember294:null>
title: title1
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after further conversation, I think your issue is linked to the API.

When you call `this.store.find('post')` Ember should make a `GET` request to the `api/v1/posts` endpoint, which should return the following JSON:

*Note: this is a plural **posts** object with an array of post objects.*

```
{
    "posts": [
        { "body": "body1", "title": "title1" },
        { "body": "body2", "title": "title2" }
    ]
}
```

When you call `this.store.find('post', { title: 'title1' })` Ember should make a `GET` request to the `api/v1/posts?title=title1` endpoint, which should return this JSON:

*Note: this is a singular **post** object with a single post object.*

```
{
    "post": { "body": "body1", "title": "title1" }
}
```

The format the JSON comes back from the server is really important, the API needs to do the filtering, Ember doesn't filter unless you ask it to.

Comment: That does not work either. This is getting really frustrating, i've tried several things and in the end i simplified everything so that the model has only a title and a body, but that did not make any difference. I've updated the original question with the new model and added some more information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In my opinion it looks like some kind of race issue where the template gets rendered before the query is fully processed.

Comment: That is really odd. As I understand it, Ember will only render the template with the query promise is fulfilled, so there shouldn't be any "race to get there first" issue. The JSON that is returned, is that the same when you have the query and when you do not?

Comment: Also, perhaps you know already, but worth saying that Ember will send a XHR request with a GET param when you use find. For example `api/v1/posts?title=title1` is your API set up to handle params like that?

Comment: Yes it is, in fact it always returns the same JSON no matter what the params are.

Comment: Ok, if the JSON is the same no matter what the parameters are then this is where the problem lies... I'll delete my first answer and update this one.

Comment: Still no success. But i'm confused, how can you do pagination then? if you need a "page" parameter and you must return a page of posts.

Comment: The Ember docs suggest using side-loaded meta data to handle pagination: [http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/) I've just reworked my API to use the JSON API spec [http://jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org) along with [this adapter](https://github.com/daliwali/ember-json-api) If you go down this route, at least you have a spec to work to!

Comment: Pleasure, if it's helpful please vote up the answer :)

Comment: I tried, but my reputation is still too low. I'll do it as soon as i can.